# Call to Micosoft OAuth2 not working as expected

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorize

I have an internal corporate web app that needs to access corporate SharePoint Online. I want to call OAuth2 to take the user through the authentication process so the web app can retrieve an access_token and then call the Microsoft Graph API. I am using Django/Python.

I have registered the app in the corporate Azure Portal, but when I call the /authorize endpoint the user sees what appears to be the wrong login page. I expect the user to see a page that shows the app's name and permissions, but all the user sees is a basic sign-on page. Moreover, when the user enters his corporate email address he sees an error that says “There was an issue looking up your account”. The user has been added to the register app's "Users and Groups".

As far as I can tell, everything is configured correctly.

I have Googled this like mad, but not found any help.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

****************** Problem solved! **************************

As it turns out, I was under the mistaken assumption that the call to the Microsoft /oauth2/v2.0/authorize endpoint should be made in the Django View code on the server (and the response of the call returned to the browser). However, an example on the Internet showed me that the call should actually be made in the browser.

In the example, the URL is constructed on the server and send to to the browser as an Anchor tag like so:

```
loginUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"
loginUrl += "?client_id={client id}"
loginUrl += "&response_type=code"
loginUrl += "&redirect_uri=" + request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('auth'))
loginUrl += "&response_mode=query"
loginUrl += "&scope={scope names}"
loginUrl += "&state={state}"
return HttpResponse('<a href="' + loginUrl + '">Click here to log in to Microsoft Online.</a>')
```

This works when I am running in my dev environment (http://127.0.0.1:8000) and from an AWS Linux server.

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Clarification: I am using Django 1.11 and Python 2.7

Comment: Update: The call to /authorize is working correctly on IE11, but failing as described above on the latest Firefox and the latest (Windows) Chrome.

Comment: How do I get the call to /authorize to work correcly on Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: Update 2: When called from a proper server, the call to /authorize is working correctly on IE11, but failing as described above on the latest Firefox and the latest (Windows) Chrome. When called from a local server (i.e., http://127.0.0.1) the call to /authorize fails as described above on all browsers.

Comment: Update 3: Actually, when called from a server, the call to /authorize is NOT working correctly on IE11. After selecting Grant Permission, I get an "Invalid parameters" errror.

Comment: Update 4: I have made some progress. After correcting a bug in my test code, the call to /authorize from a server is working correctly on IE11 only. When I try to same test on Chrome I get the error shown below. It seems to have something to do with CORS.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Failed to load https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/GetCredentialType?mkt=en-US: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://test-insight.lonzagroup.net' is therefore not allowed access.
AjaxHandlerControl.js:111 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/GetCredentialType?mkt=en-US with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

Comment: Problem solved! See original post for solution.